# Ignore html the data in html data-* attribute while exporting to csv jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, html, csv, datatables

I am using `jQuery data-tables` export buttons to export data as CSV from my tables.

The table has a title column in which each title is diplayed as a hyper-link with data-content attribute. This attribute has data in html tags like `<strong></strong>` and in `lists`.

The problem is that when I export the data as CSV, this additional data which is supposed to get displayed only when clicked and has no concern with CSV is also exported to the title column of CSV.

I want to stop this and only get the title.
I apologize if I am not clear I will explain it further as I will be asked.

Comment: Incredible this question has got 4 upvotes in 5 hours  :) There is no base for an answer, except trying to reproduce the scenario from imagination in order to provide a meaningful, useful answer people in the future can understand.

Comment: I have solved the problem on my own and I will provide with a detailed answer for this.